# Зацикливание ArrayAdapter для Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, arrayadapter

Я начинающий Android разработчик. Столкнулся при создании кастомного ArrayAdapter с зацикливанием элементов внутри Spinner, которому и передается некий список через ArrayAdapter. Каждые 15 элементов происходит повторение одних и тех же элементов из передаваемой коллекции
типа ArrayList. Сама коллекция не маленькая (300+ элементов).

Вот класс кастомного ArrayAdapter:

```
public class SpinnerBonds extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SpinnerBonds(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NotNull ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_bonds,null,true);
        String sSec=(String) getItem(position);
        TextView tv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_security); //TxtView в который записывается элемент коллекции list
        tv.setText(sSec);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_bonds,parent,false);
            String sSec=(String) getItem(position);
            TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_security);
            tv.setText(sSec);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Вот так в него передается некий `ArrayList<String> list_sec`, состоящий из большого количества позиций.

```
SpinnerBonds bondsAdapter = new SpinnerBonds(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_bonds,list_sec);
spinnerSec.setAdapter(bondsAdapter);
```

В итоге, в spinnerSec создается большое кол-во элементов, но все элементы повторяются каждые 15 позиций.
Что делать уже просто не знаю. Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас происходит ровно то, что написано в коде)

Адаптер переиспользует ранее заинфлейшенные вьюхи. А ранее заинфлейшенные вьюхи вы уже наполнили данными. В итоге у вас метод `getDropDownView` вызывается 15 раз с `convertView` равному null, а остальные разы - с `convertView` не равному `null` и с уже заполненным `TextView`.

Соответственно, вам надо написать также и переназначение текста во вьюхе, которая переиспользуется:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_bonds,parent,false);
    }

    String sSec=(String) getItem(position);
    TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_security);
    tv.setText(sSec);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо Вам большое и человеческое! Буду еще изучать этот элемент!

Comment: @justshurik, пожалуйта) Если ответ вам помог - вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: Для Вас - все что угодно )